# Transacting with a Jewish owned company who profited from chometz on Pesach

Tags: passover, money, chametz-leaven, business, hametz-sheavar-alav-pesah

In my neighborhood there is a supermarket which is owned by a non-religious Jew. He keeps it open over Pesach and sells (and presumably buys) chometz. The community does not purchase chometz items from that store for 2 weeks afterwards, which is time enough for all the chometz items which had been owned over Pesach to cycle through the store and be replenished.

My question is: is there any prohibition attached to the money made through the selling of chometz over Pesach? Meaning, for example, if the store owner sold a loaf of bread on Pesach and now wants to use that exact same physical money from that sale to buy something from is there any prohibition involved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gemara in [kiddushin 58a](http://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.58a?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all) says that the only *issurei hana'ah* that have a problem of *tefisat damim* (the prohibition of the monetary exchange) are *avoda zara* (idolatry), *hekdesh* (consecrated items**), and *peirot shevi'it* (produce of the sabbatical year from the land of Israel; I believe even the idolatry issue is only with regard to *tikrovet avoda zara* [idolatrous offerings; e.g. [the issue was raised with regard to wigs made with the hairs used in Hindu religious rituals](http://ohr.edu/1698)]). However, the money from sale of *chametz she'avar alav hapesach* (or even from the sale of an idol itself) should not be an issue (see also: http://download.yutorah.org/2006/1053/735070.pdf).

**I believe this extends, at least rabbinically, to other holy items such as synagogues and Torah scrolls.